# How to search through my index through the array and find the match then move it to the last index in php?

Tags: php

I will have set of array which comes in the form like this

```
<?php
$month = array(
[0]=>array("title"=>"Jan",
"key"=>1,
"value"=>1),
[1]=>array("title"=>"Feb",//index "value" not set
"key"=>1
),
[2]=>array("title"=>"March",
"key"=>1,
"value"=>1),
[3]=>array("title"=>"Apr", //index "value" not set
"key"=>1
),
[4]=>array("title"=>"May",
"key"=>1,
"value"=>1),
[5]=>array("title"=>"June", 
"key"=>1,
"value"=>1)
) ?>
```

For index [1] and index[3], the "value" is not set. I would like to take these two array and arrange at the end of the array.
In the end, the result would be like this in the below..

```
<?php
//Desired Result
$months = array(
[0]=>array("title"=>"Jan",
"key"=>1,
"value"=>1),
[1]=>array("title"=>"March",
"key"=>1,
"value"=>1),
[2]=>array("title"=>"May",
"key"=>1,
"value"=>1),
[3]=>array("title"=>"June",
"key"=>1,
"value"=>1),
[4]=>array("title"=>"Feb",  //the without "value" will be changed to here
"key"=>1),
[5]=>array("title"=>"Apr", //the without "value" will be changed to here
"key"=>1)
) ?>
```

So, I need to check whether name "value" exist in the array using looping, if it is not exist , it would need to be transferred to the end of the the array. 
How to perform this movement?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array and check if each sub-array has a `value` element. If it doesn't, push it to `$monthsWithoutIndices`. If it does, push it to `$monthsWithIndices`. Once the looping is over, join these two arrays together using [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) to obtain the final result:

```
$monthsWithIndices = array();
$monthsWithoutIndices = array();

foreach ($month as $key => $arr) 
{
    if (!isset($arr['value'])) 
    {   // If it doesn't have a 'value'
        $monthsWithoutIndices[] = $arr;
    } 
    else 
    {   // If it has a 'value'
        $monthsWithIndices[] = $arr;
    }
}

// Join the two arrays
$result = array_merge($monthsWithIndices, $monthsWithoutIndices);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/133921)